# Adding hooks to functions in subclassed methods

Tags: python, inheritance

Given the following simplified code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.parent_name = 'SuperClass'
    
    # global hook to run before each subclass run()
    def global_pre_run_hook(self):
        pass
    
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

        
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.name = 'ChildClass'
    
    def run(self):
        print(f'my parent name is {self.parent_name}')
        print(f'my name is {self.name}')
        
        return 22
        
obj = Child()
result = obj.run()
```

Is there a way to add functionality so that when the child class `run()` method is called directly, it first triggers a **hook function** from the parent class?  Assume there is a parent class and a lot of classes that subclass it - would I need to manually add a `call global hook()` at the beginning of each `run()` definition for each class that subclasses `Parent()`?  Is there a *pythonic* way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm sure that's possible with some metaclass trickery, but the straightforward solution would be to simply not call `.run()` directly - instead call your hook method (which is implemented only in the base class), and have `self.run()` in that method.

Comment: @jasonharper interesting. I'm trying to get inspiration from pytorch's `forward()` method that overrides the base `Module` `forward` method, but allows global forward pre hooks, as well as sub-class specific pre hooks https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L716 , but you still end up calling the subclass `forward` routine directly. Not sure how they accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a way to do this with a proper decorator, but for the time being I think the cleanest solution you might come up with would be to create your own 'decorator' and manually apply it in the course of `Parent.__init__()`, which would make sure it takes effect so long as the child class invokes the parent `__init__()`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

def create_hook(func, hook):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        hook()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent_name = 'SuperClass'
        self.run = create_hook(self.run, self.global_pre_run_hook)

    # global hook to run before each subclass run()
    def global_pre_run_hook(self):
        print("Hooked")

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.name = 'ChildClass'

    def run(self):
        print(f'my parent name is {self.parent_name}')
        print(f'my name is {self.name}')
        return 22

obj = Child()
result = obj.run()
# this prints:
#   Hooked
#   my parent name is SuperClass
#   my name is ChildClass
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Green Cloak Guy works, **but cannot be pickled**! To fix this, we need to move the hook creation into **`__new__`**. Also, it's a good idea to make use of **`functools.wraps`** in the hook creator.

```py
import pickle
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from functools import wraps

def create_hook(func, hook):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        hook(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Parent(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.run = create_hook(cls.run, cls.global_pre_run_hook)
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    # global hook to run before each subclass run()
    def global_pre_run_hook(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Hooked")

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Child(Parent):
    def run(self):
        print(f"my parents are {self.__class__.__mro__}")
        print(f"my name is {self.__class__.__name__}")
        return 22

obj = Child()
result = obj.run()
pickle.dumps(obj)
```